# Cast derived class type dynamically to base class type C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, class, inheritance, reflection

```
public DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
   // code
}

DerivedClass B = (DerivedClass)MethodReturnsBaseClassObject();
B.DoWork();
```

There are many Derived classes being inherited from `BaseClass`. So everytime i need to write a new method to use some of the properties.

Is this possible that using reflection we make `DerivedClass` type dynamic and do something like this and make it generic.

```
System.Type type = GetRequestFromSession().GetType();
type B = (type )MethodReturnsBaseClassObject();
Console.WriteLine( B.Name);  
Console.WriteLine( B.Age);
```

any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you considered dynamic types:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx   or ExpandoObject   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject(v=vs.110).aspx?     Here is also an msdn blog on the subject:   https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/csharpfaq/2009/09/30/dynamic-in-c-4-0-introducing-the-expandoobject/

Comment: I assume you can´t simply declare `Name` and `Age` on `BaseClass`, can you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This feels like bad design to me: you make something generic that you use as something that isn't. Maybe you should rethink your design.

For what your question is concerned, maybe you can create a proxy method or class that returns the type you expect. This is only useful when there is a low number of methods you call.

Another option is to use the `dynamic` keyword, but I would advice only to use that if nothing else works.

Comment: I know its a very bad design. But i need to make it generic. There are 34 identical methods written in allover application. I want to make one method for better maintenance in future

Comment: Thank you Patrick. Using dynamic with this design did fix it...But sorry about bad design i am newly working on this application.

Answer (score 5):

You can have safe access to members of the derived type (without casts) while enforcing the base class constraint if you employ a generic method with the following signature:

```
public TDerived MethodReturnsDerivedObject<TDerived>()
    where TDerived : BaseClass
```

Your calls will then look like this:

```
DerivedClass b = MethodReturnsDerivedObject<DerviedClass>();

b.ExecuteSomeMethodDefinedInBaseClass();

Console.WriteLine(b.SomePropertyDefinedInDerivedClass);
```

Comment: This is way better than using dynamic IMO.

Comment: Yeh, something like this using generics would be the way to go.

Comment: this will be a common implementation for many derived types. I used dynamic because with the use of `dynamic` i wont have to change my design. But for this i will have to know the type of derived class first.

Answer (score 2):

I would go with Kirill Shlenskiy's answer for now. But I'd also like to suggest moving this method onto the base class itself *if it makes sense to do so*. There may be tangled dependencies or other weirdness that prohibits this solution, but it may also allow you to have one consumer without using generics.